# How to use more then one xml file in Activity Kotlin

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, kotlin

Is there any chance to initialize more then one `.xml` file and use there elements when i want?

Here is my android code:

```
   mStepOneView                    = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_exclusion_length, null);
   mStepTwoView                    = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_gambling_sites, null);
   mStepThreeView                  = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_info_sites, null);
   mStepFourView                   = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_websites, null);
   mStepFiveView                   = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_activate_self_exclusion, null);
```

I have a container in which I am replace different step - every step is different `.xml` layout and i got every element from from these xml files. I want to do this in **Kotlin**, the problem is that if mStepOneView is inflated i can't get element value from mStepTwoView.

Comment: What does "i can't get element value from mStepTwoView" mean?

Comment: For example, i have edittext in stepOneView and stepTwoView, in stepFour i need to show values which user is selected and i need to get this edittext values from step one and two

Comment: Kotlin is a programming language. Android is an operating system. Hence, "in android this worked well and i wan't to do this in kotlin" does not make much sense.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, it worked well in java way

Comment: Your Kotlin can be a simple conversion from Java. You can even have Android Studio convert the Java to Kotlin for you. So, you might wish to show your Kotlin code as part of a [mcve] and explain in detail what problems you have with it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you are using the wrong approach either you should use fragments (Maybe child if your parent is already a fragment) or you should declare an empty layout inside your main layout and only add your other XML like layout dynamically. you can use below code.

```
// get your inner relative layout child
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findById(R.id.rl);


// inflate content layout(Other XML file) and add it to the relative 
// layout as a child and update it with different layout (XML) files conditionally 

LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
        this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);    
rl.addView(1, layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.content_layout, this, false) );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can handle it by adding "include" to the main xml keyword and control the visibility of each xml layout.
So you will need to inflate an xml layout that contains all the layouts and control which xml layout to show by getting the layout with id and set visibility gone or visible and so on.

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include 
          android:id="@+id/activity_exclusion_length"
          layout="@layout/activity_exclusion_length" />
       <include layout="@layout/activity_gambling_sites" />
       <include layout="@layout/activity_info_sites" />

 <LinearLayout/>
```

Comment: Yes i agree with you, but why i can't inflate them as i do it with java code because if i need to check for visibility my method will be 100 lines